# Error 99 on Canon 1000d

Tags: canon, error, canon-1000d

I am getting this **Error 99**, when I turn the Power switch "**Off**" and then turn it back "**On**". 
I am using an 18-55 Lens and I found somewhere that flapping the SD Card Slot will resolve this, it did.
However now when I turn the Power switch to "**Off**" and then turn it back to "**On**", I do not get the display on the screen, only when i remove the Battery and put it back on, I get the display back.
Is this a known issue in Canon 1000D ? Will a firmware update resolve the issue ?

Comment: The Link provided gives me a Page Not Found error http://richardsnotes.org/archives/2005/04/29/50mm-lens-contact-points/

Comment: I have also followed the steps provided, it did not solve the issue.
When I took it to the Canon Service, the technician said,it is when either the Battery Slot or the Memory Card slot is not closed, which is unlikely in my case. I had both the slots closed completely.